# Is there any function whose Laplace Transform does not have a pole or singularity?

Tags: laplace-transform

The Laplace Transforms of all functions I know have poles.

1. Can there be a function $F$ whose Laplace transform does not have a pole (or any other singularity)?
2. If so, is it possible that the function $F$ itself does not have poles or zeros?

Comment: It might happen that both $f$ and $\mathcal{L} f$ are entire functions, like in the $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ case. If you further require that both $f$ and $\mathcal{L} f$ are "nice"... well, that does not happen.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Thanks!  What do you mean by 'nice' here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any function which decays sufficiently fast has a Laplace transform with no poles. Examples include $e^{-x^2/2}$ and $1_{[0,1]}$ (the function that is $1$ on $[0,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere) (there may appear to be a singularity in the latter's Laplace transform, $(1-e^{-s})/s$ at $s=0$, but there actually isn't since $\int_0^1 \, dx=1$ is finite).

Comment: Thanks! If I may ask a stupid question, what if I have $\int \sqrt{t} F(t) e^{-st}$, can there still be an entire function F(t) that does the job? i.e whose Laplace Transform is an entire function?

Comment: I suppose $F(t) = e^{-t^4}$ should do the job, as $\sqrt{t} e^{-t^4}$ falls off faster than $e^{-t^2}$ ?

Comment: For the Laplace transform to be entire, it is necessary that the integral converges for any value of $s$. $e^{-t^2}$ fast enough that any polynomial times $e^{-t^2}$ is also fine (or, indeed, $e^{at}$ for any $a$), so $e^{-t^2}$ will still work.

Comment: @Chappers  If $f$ decreases faster than any exponential then its Laplace transform analytic everywhere. No poles is ambiguous as the singularities can be of any sort, not only poles. **And some functions** have an entire Laplace transform without decreasing faster than any exponential, this is the case for $(e^u-\lfloor e^u \rfloor) 1_{u > 0} $ as well as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \varphi(u-\ln n), \varphi \in C^\infty_c$ (a consequence of $\zeta(s)-\frac{1}{s-1}$ being entire)